# TPL return value and exception

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

I have develop a library that connects and operate with devices.
For example:

```
public bool Connect(string ip)
{
    try
    {
        // try connect to device
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // trow custom exception
    }
}
```

This is ok, but now I have decided to include in my library TPL.

The problem I'm facing is with the logic of how to return values.
Instead of passing an IP, you will pass a list of IP's.
Imagine you want to connect to 10 devices and 5 are ok and the other 5 are faulted I image a code like:

```
public Dictionary<Device, bool> Connect(List<Device> device)
{
    try
    {
        // TPL try connect to device
    }
    catch (AggregatedException ex)
    {
        // trow custom exception
    }
}
```

If someone calls this method they would only receive the exeption, in this case it can be easy but for example, if I have another method like `Dictionary<Device, List<Logs>> GetLogs(List<Device> device)` I would have 5 devices with data and 5 devices faulted.

What is the best way to return a result for the correct connections and the errors for the faulted ones? A connection can fail for several reasons.

UPDATE

I have tried this:

```
    public Dictionary<int, Task<string>> GetData3(int value)
    {
        Dictionary<int, Task<string>> dic = new Dictionary<int, Task<string>>();
        Task<string>[] tasks = new Task<string>[value];
        for (int i = 0; i < value; i++)
        {
            tasks[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew<string>((stateObject) =>
            {
                var a = (int)stateObject;
                return a + " Test";
            }, value);
            dic.Add(i, tasks[i]);
        }
        Task.WaitAll(tasks);

        return dic;
    }
```

And in the WS Client:

```
        Service1Client sc = new Service1Client();
        var a = sc.GetData3(5);
```

If i break in `return dic` i can see the results:

```
Id = 1, Status = RanToCompletion, Method = "{null}", Result = "5 Test"
```

But in `var a` I only see:

```
Id = 1, Status = WaitingForActivation, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet computed}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could return a `Dictionary<Device, Task<Whatever>>` (where `Whatever` would be the result for each device). You could return that *immediately*, having started connecting to each device. Then the task would represent (on a per-device basis) whether the connection had completed, failed, or was still on-going.

Aside from anything else, using tasks for asynchronous results is pretty much the idiomatic way of using TPL... and made easier in C# 5 with async/await.

If the caller wants to wait for all of the tasks to complete, and aggregate any exceptions, they can do so.

Comment: Some customers use this as an SDK, but we have an extension that uses this same SDK to create a WCF. Some of the people that uses the WCF use php. What would you think of creating: DeviceResult : Device and include a bool for error and the exception?

Comment: @Eisenrich: It feels like by doing that, you're negating half the benefit of using TPL at all. Personally I think that the task-based approach is the cleanest and most idiomatic.